# List has no rows for assignment to SObject in a test class

Tags: unit-test

I need to  create a test class for the below mentioned class so far I am getting the error "List has no rows for assignment ".Here customer address is an object whose parent is contact

```
Public with sharing class WelcomePageController {

    Public WelcomePageController (){

    }

    Public String getCustomerAddressId() {
        Id runningUserid=userinfo.getUserid();

        User user=[SELECT ID,ContactId FROM User WHERE IsActive=True AND ID=:runningUserid];
        system.debug('user@@@@@'+user);

        Contact contact=[SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE ID=:user.ContactId ];
        system.debug('contact@@@@@'+contact);

        Customer_Address__c customerAddress=[SELECT ID,Customer__c,Customer_Address_ID__c FROM Customer_Address__c WHERE Customer__c =:contact.Id ];
        system.debug('customerAddress@@@@@'+customerAddress);

        return customerAddress.Customer_Address_ID__c ;
    }

   Public PageReference finishRegistration() {
       PageReference page = new PageReference('/apex/Dashboard');
       page.setredirect(true);
       return page;
   }    
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest(seeAlldata=False)
    public class WelcomePageController_Test {

    @isTest
    public static void testWelcomePageController(){
        Profile profile = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Profile WHERE Name='Customer Community Login User']; 

        Account account = new Account(Name='Test Account Name');
        insert account;

        Contact contact=new Contact();
        contact.LastName='Test';
        contact.AccountId=account.Id;
        insert contact;

        User user=new User();
        user.Email='test@force.com';
        user.Username='test@force.com';
        user.LastName='Test';
        user.Alias='testf';
        user.CommunityNickname='test@force.com';
        user.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
        user.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
        user.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
        user.ProfileId=profile.Id;
        user.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
        user.ContactId=contact.id;
        user.IsActive = true;
        //user.UserRole=;
        insert user;
        WelcomePageController welcomePageController = new WelcomePageController();
        //welcomePageController.runningUserid='005P0000001bEjB';
        WelcomePageController.finishRegistration();
        WelcomePageController.getCustomerAddressId();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Contact` is parent for `Customer_Address__c` Object, there might be case that one `Contact` can have multiple `Customer_Address__c` Object.

So replace this line:

```
Customer_Address__c customerAddress=[SELECT ID,Customer__c,Customer_Address_ID__c FROM Customer_Address__c WHERE Customer__c =:contact.Id ];
```

With:

```
List<Customer_Address__c> customerAddressList=[SELECT ID,Customer__c,Customer_Address_ID__c FROM Customer_Address__c WHERE Customer__c =:contact.Id ];
```

Also in your test class you're not creating `customer_address__c` data. That's why you're getting that error. Add below lines after inserting `contact` in your test class:

```
Customer_Address__c  customer = new Customer_Address__c ();
customer.Customer__c = contact.id;
customer.Customer_Address_ID__c  = 'customer Id';
insert customer;
```

Comment: I made the required changes but still I am getting the sameerror

Comment: @SaswataDas on which line you're getting an error.?

Comment: I am getting the error in this line WelcomePageController.getCustomerAddressId();

Comment: Are you returning like this: `return customerAddressList[0].Customer_Address_ID__c ;` because now it would a list . Also since you've made some changes. Post your code.

Comment: yes I m doing exactly the same but still it is showing the same exception

Comment: @SaswataDas Update your code and also look at the stacktrace of your error. `WelcomePageController.getCustomerAddressId();` is last trace. Go up the order to get the exact line number were you're getting a error

Comment: The problem seems to lie in the line Contact contact=[SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE ID=:user.ContactId ];
        system.debug('contact@@@@@'+contact); in actual case when the user is created through community page a contact record gets created corresponding to that user .The same thing I need to show with the test class.

Comment: @SaswataDas Before calling `getCustomerAddressId()` from test class, add `System.runAs(user)` since you're retrieving current logged in user in your controller.